# WPF Binding XML List

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, binding

I want to bind the following XML to a couple of controls in WPF.

Each category name should bind to the items source of a combo box, then when a category is selected in the combo box I want to bind the list of Products from the selected category to a listview

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Categories>
  <Category Name="Category1">
    <Products>
      <Product Name="Product 1"/>
      <Product Name="Product 2"/>
    </Products>
  </Category>
  <Category Name="Category2">
    <Products>
      <Product Name="Product 1"/>
      <Product Name="Product 2"/>
      <Product Name="Product 3"/>
    </Products>
  </Category>
</Categories>
```

and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your xml into a file called Categories.xml, and this should work...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="categoryTemplate" DataType="Category">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="productTemplate" DataType="Product">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider
            Source="Categories.xml" XPath="/Categories/Category" />
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <ComboBox
        x:Name="categoryComboBox"
        Grid.Row="0" Margin="8"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource categoryTemplate}" />

    <ListView
        Grid.Row="1" Margin="8"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Products/Product}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource productTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, Nice and simple...!